# return null when pass virable to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, transfer

I'm trying to send data on `SharedPreferenceson` from `MainActivity` to a `BroadcastReceiver`.
but that always return `null` .
I tried very code but all of them returned `null`.

this is my code on `MainActivity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     SharedPreferences shpMobile = getSharedPreferences("text", MODE_PRIVATE);
     final String MobileNumber = (shpMobile.getString("MobileDevice", "0"));
  Intent inte = new Intent();
    inte.setAction("MyBroadcast");

    inte.putExtra("Phone", MobileNumber);

    sendBroadcast(inte);
```

and this is my `BroadcastReceiver` class

```
String phoo1;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        //updateWidget();


        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
         if (extras != null) {

          String phoo1 = (String) extras.get("Phone");//getting null value

          Toast.makeText(context, phoo1 +"این شماره انتقال دهنده است", 5000).show();
         }
```

But `phoo` is `null`.
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all.
but i cant get value with this solution. and i was searched on net to find another way to get the values.
finally ,i find a new sulotion . code is in below: ( i used to Shareperferenced to get values in BroadcastReceiver)

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("text", 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     final String MobileNumber = (prefs.getString("MobileDevice", null));
```

this code work for me and reply the our Qustion for  @Opiatefuchs request

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem some time ago. Try it using getStringExtra() from the intent instead of extras.get() from bundle:

```
String phoo1 = intent.getStringExtra("Phone");
```

that solved my problem.

Comment: if you pass integer intent.putExtra("Name",100) use intent.getIntExtrs("Name",-1) ===> returns -1 if intent does not have "Name". if you pass String intent.putExtra("Name","100") use intent.getStringExtrs("Name")===>returns null if intent does not have "Name". And putting int and fetching using getStringExtra(), also give null

Comment: what? don´t understand? Should this be an answer for the question from Aliblk?

Comment: Just added a bit more explanation to support your answer.

Comment: i am sending string and use getStringExtrs ، but returned Null, can give me an example or explane more. im confuse

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to replace this code:
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   String phoo1 = (String) extras.get("Phone");//getting null value
   Toast.makeText(context, phoo1 +"این شماره انتقال دهنده است", 5000).show();
}

With this:
String phoo1 = intent.getStringExtra("Phone") !=null? intent.getStringExtra("Phone"):"";
Toast.makeText(context, phoo1 +"این شماره انتقال دهنده است", 5000).show();
```

Comment: this code was returned error for me . getIntent(). has unknowned in BroadcastReceiver